# How to install .Net Core on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I can't find any proper explanation with active links to SDKs on how to install .Net Core on Visual Studio 2015.

I'm lost, please advice on how to install it on VS 2015?

Comment: Why do you get lost? It is so clear a Visual Studio 2017 only thing, or you can use Visual Studio Code plus the SDK. Visual Studio 2015 is too old to support new things like .NET Core. Forget about it.

Comment: @LexLi ok, So I can't even run the old .Net Core 1.0 on VS 2015?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only .NET Core runtime versions that work with VS 2015 is RC1, RC2, and 1.0. And the tooling will only work up to preview4. You also have to have update 3 installed. Better just to use VS 2017 or the CLI.

Comment: Ok, Do you have any links to the .Net Core version thats running with VS2015?

Comment: Thank u! Exaclty what I needed

Comment: That's preview tooling for VS2015, and has far too many issues compared to what VS2017 offers. Thus, I never think it should be recommended to anyone right now.